# Where does pip install files?

Tags: python, github, pip

[image: githubexample]

Where do Github files like these get installed onto my computer by pip? I want to run pytest files within this file structure.

Comment: What operating system are you using? File paths look different on each OS, and Python has different install locations based on that, too.

Comment: why not jst clone the repo?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you have two things confused.

When you normally install a package with `pip`, it downloads the "release files" of that package from [PyPi](https://pypi.org/), then installs all the relevant files needed to **use the package**, to your local Python's *site-packages* folder. The location of the *site-packages* depends on your Python/`pip` config, your operating system, and whether or not you are using a virtual environment.

If this is just regular `pip`, you can use [`pip show`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_show/) to tell you where it installed things. For example, installing the [EasyGA package from PyPi](https://pypi.org/project/EasyGA/) using Python3.8 on a Mac:

```
$ python3 -V
Python 3.8.5

$ python3 -m pip install EasyGA
...
Installing collected packages: blessings, EasyGA
Successfully installed EasyGA-0.0.8 blessings-1.7

$ python3 -m pip show EasyGA
Name: EasyGA
Version: 0.0.8
Summary: A ubiquitous or general purpuse GA
Home-page: https://github.com/danielwilczak101/EasyGA
...
Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages
...
```

..shows that it is installed in */usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages*. But when you head over there:

```
$ cd /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages
$ ls -l
total 60736
-rwxr-xr-x    1 gino  admin  19681392 Sep  5 10:42 3220aef3144e83d3e26a__mypyc.cpython-38-darwin.so
drwxr-xr-x    8 gino  admin       256 Sep 26 19:20 EasyGA-0.0.8.dist-info
-rw-r--r--    1 gino  admin      1800 Sep 26 19:20 EasyGA.py
...
```

..there seems to be no "file structure" here. The files installed there are **just meant to be used or imported in your applications or scripts**, and are **not meant for development or testing**. It is usually the "release version" of a package. So, asking where `pip` installs things because you want to "run pytest files within this file structure" does not make much sense (to me, at least).

If you want to run tests on the package, the best way is to get a copy of the package's "raw" source codes. Since it is hosted on Github, you need to use `git` to [clone the source codes](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Getting-a-Git-Repository) from the repo URL or download them as a ZIP:

[image]

You could also check the package's files in PyPi if the author provides the the source codes for download. For EasyGA, it is available as [EasyGA-0.0.8.tar.gz](https://pypi.org/project/EasyGA/#files).

Whichever way you choose to get the source codes, you should then end up with an *EasyGA* folder (if you `git clone`-d it) or a *EasyGA-master* folder (if you downloaded it as a .zip then unzipped it) or a *EasyGA-0.0.8* folder (if you downloaded the .tar.gz from PyPi then untar-ed it). The contents are all the same, the "raw" source codes of the package:

```
$ ls
EasyGA            
EasyGA-0.0.8
EasyGA-0.0.8.tar.gz
EasyGA-master     
EasyGA-master.zip

$ ls EasyGA
LICENSE.txt MANIFEST.in README.md   setup.py    src

$ ls EasyGA-0.0.8
MANIFEST.in PKG-INFO    README.md   setup.cfg   setup.py    src

$ ls EasyGA-master
LICENSE.txt MANIFEST.in README.md   setup.py    src
```

**Notice now that the contents are the same as what's on the Github page** you are referencing. Then just follow the author's instructions for [How Testing works](https://github.com/danielwilczak101/EasyGA#how-testing-works):

```
$ cd EasyGA
$ ls
LICENSE.txt MANIFEST.in README.md   setup.py    src

$ python3 -m pip install pytest
Collecting pytest
  Downloading pytest-6.0.2-py3-none-any.whl (270 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 270 kB 2.6 MB/s 
...
Successfully installed attrs-20.2.0 iniconfig-1.0.1 more-itertools-8.5.0 packaging-20.4 pluggy-0.13.1 py-1.9.0 pyparsing-2.4.7 pytest-6.0.2 toml-0.10.1

$ pytest
================================================================== test session starts ===================================================================
platform darwin -- Python 3.8.5, pytest-6.0.2, py-1.9.0, pluggy-0.13.1
rootdir: /path/to/EasyGA
collected 1 item                                                                                                                                         

src/initialization/gene_structure/test_gene.py .                                                                                                   [100%]

=================================================================== 1 passed in 0.03s ====================================================================
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find where the package is installed then search for the "EasyGA" folder after you pip install. This approach works with windows,mac and ubuntu linux.

A new EasyGA package has been uploaded and has all the pip install bugs fixed.

And anyone looking to use the python package and wants to know more just check out the wiki. We love to use "among us" characters in our tutorials.

EasyGA Wiki: https://github.com/danielwilczak101/EasyGA/wiki

Among us tutorial: https://github.com/danielwilczak101/EasyGA/wiki/Setup-and-Attributes